# Debugger source path mapping with static libs in QTCreator 4.0.0

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm trying to debug a project where libraries are stored at a different location at runtime from when they are built. For .so libraries, I can just use the source path mapping from Tools->Options->Debugger->General .

However, for statically linked .a files, the stack view won't show me the "source path as seen by the debugger".

How should I handle this case?

Regards